# How to keep front whole number in Tcl

Tags: integer, tcl

How to keep the first five integers in TCL?
For example:
set x 12058934562

I expect to get result 12058

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to handle that as "this number divided by one million" or "just take the first 5 characters from this string"?

Comment: I just want to take the first 5 characters from the string, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat the variable as a string and return the first five characters (which are expected to be integers):

```
string range $x 0 4
  --> 12058
```

Comment: @Tedarencn: docs => https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm